# STM32H7 Heating

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, stm32, heat, short-circuit

I have been working on a SMT32H747 MCU based HV PCB board. The power supply pins of MCU is only supplied with 3.3V (max can supply 3A). Moreover, I also connected MCU's VDD1V2 (1.2V) pins with 3.3V.

Issue noticed so far, MCU is heating too much. And damaged couple of IC.

Note - MCU is not loaded with any firmware, still heats up. I'm suspecting short circuit on power supply pins of MCU.

Can anyone help me finding short circuit nets here? Also provide me your suggestions. Thanks

MCU Power supply section image (Sorry for confusing schematic net names)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GzGd.jpg

Comment: Without having looked into the data sheet: Do you think it is correct to "_connect[ed] MCU's VDD1V2 (1.2V) pins with 3.3V_"?

Comment: @thebusybee I've followed dev kit schematic, but not sure if this is correct or not. Can you help me with finding any short ckt nets here?

Comment: Ram Prakash - This is a duplicate of your previous post. **Do not** repost the same question, even if it is "closed" (i.e. waiting for you to improve it or add missing details etc.). It wastes the time of people who already started to look at your previous question. :( Now that you have added the schematics there, I will reopen that question, to see if other site members can help.

Answer (score 0):

The MCU is heating up because it's on.
It can have a maximum junction temperature of 125 C. *Did you measure with the internal sensor?*

Depending on what you is enabled and how much current the gpio's are doing, the energy loss is higher.
See chapter "6.3.7 Supply current characteristics" in the manual.

50C is nothing to worry about yet.

Comment: I've damaged couple of MCU, the temp is continuously increasing. Could you please see power supply pins of STM32?

Comment: MCU is not loaded with firmware, it still heats up. I am doubting my power supply pins of MCU. There is somewhere short circuit.

Comment: H7 will not heat up. I have one running in front of me and cant feel any heating at all.